# Are my corn leaves too yellow?

Tags: corn

I recently planted corn in my garden and I'm noticing that their leaves are a yellow-green.  I did add a nitrogen fertilizer and it seemed to help a bit.  However, when driving by farms I notice that the corn leaves in a farmer's field are a deep green.  Are my leaves too yellow? (Picture below)

[image]

Comment: It's been above 20c but really rainy. The temperature has also been a roller coaster. Yesterday was 20c but the day before was around 30.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Chlorophyll_d_structure.svg I am no corn expert, but chlorophyll (what makes plants green) needs N and Mg to be formed. You've already added N, could be Mg deficiency. But again, I have no idea how young corn should look.

Answer (score 2):

You've planted around 20 corn plants or more in 16 square feet?  You need to thin your corn plants to a more reasonable number. Have you fertilized?  Your corn leaves are way too yellow.

Get some basic balanced fertilizer; Osmocote 14-14-14 extended release.  Easy, safe and really saves time. A balanced fertilizer with the three main ingredients have a percentage number each.  Corn?  If you've given it an application of high percentage formulation of nitrogen then now you have to use NPK formulation where the N is a lower percentage of P and K!  If you want corn instead of leaves.

Pull all but 6 or 8 corn plants.  What are you using and what have you used to give your plants the proper chemicals to do photosynthesis? Have to have fertilizer!  Not compost but fertilizer.  btw what soil did you put in your raised beds?

Comment: Interesting. I've read that in square foot gardening the corn can be that close. That's the method I was following anyway. I'm using an 18-10-10 at the moment. The soil is compost, dirt, and extra manure.

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky I don't know what you read but the scientific studies I read state that clusters of 3-9 plants perform better than traditional 1' spacing, given the same total of plants not that you can plant dozens of plants in an enclosed space. That "raised" bed is basically a pot to a shallow rooted plant. They don't look all that yellow to me, but it's either overcrowding or underfertilizing due to rain.